# getting the write permission for sd card

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, android-emulator

I can't mount my sd card on the emulator and it gives me only a read option for the sd card as shown below :

[image]

How do i get the write permission on the virtual sd card so that i am able to push some media onto the sd card to test my applications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the shell. Open your prompt, type:

```
adb shell
```

Then, remount your sdcard with rw permissions.

```
mount -o remount rw /sdcard
```

**EDIT**

sdcard without permissions:

[image]

Opening the shell:

[image]

change of permissions:

[image]

Comment: i get an error saying that device not found. I want to do this on my emulator not on the real device

Comment: You need to launch your emulator before opening the shell for your emulator. You can access the shell for your emulator in the same manner you can do for your device. Do not connect your device while running the adb command. Power on your emulator then go for the above steps.

Comment: [gives me a invalid argument error,when i run the command to remount](http://i48.tinypic.com/34dizrr.jpg)

Comment: your sdcard is not mounted properly.

Comment: just run `mount` on your shell to know if your sdcard is mounted.

Comment: Yup. Your sdcard isn't mounted.

Comment: Have you added a sdcard to your emulator? Check once by opening AVD Manager > Selecting your device > Details.

Comment: but i mentioned the sd card size while making the virtual device a.k.a emulator. How can i mount now ?

Comment: If you have a sdcard, simply type `mount /sdcard` in your shell.

Comment: You have a sdcard, just try the `mount` command I just gave you.

Comment: i don't know why,but i have started getting `error:device offline` after i run the `mount /sdcard` the eclipse doesn't show anything in the file-explorer and log cat doesn't logs !

Comment: restart your `AVD` or create a new `AVD` as the other answer suggests.

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680417/error-device-offline if your problem persists. :-)

Comment: [now when i have read-write permissions i can't see the images on the emulator i have pushed . what could be the reason ? I can see `IMG_201`,the image that i captured using the emulator but can't see the `bea.jpg` and `amsterdam.jpg` that i have pushed onto the emulator](http://i45.tinypic.com/33yt9ut.jpg)

Comment: I don't have much of an idea about it. Post this as a new question, maybe someone might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you can created the SDCard for the Emulator by giving its `size` under

`SD Card` - Tab and also you have added `SD Card Support` to your device under `Hardware` - Tab

[image]

Comment: I would insist you to try to create another AVD and try it.

Answer (score 0):

use your AVD manager and specify that the AVD target has an sd card on the virtualization. Also Google limits the emulated card to 50Mb, at least they used to. So just open eclipse, bring up your AVD manager from the menu bar and edit the target AVD emulation to have a card installed, then input write permission in your android manifest file for permission, should work fine from there.

Answer (score 0):

less then 1024 MB size of sdcard in avd ->to edit 
then save 
then run