# adb unable to connect to Android-x86 in VirtualBox today

Tags: android, adb, virtualbox, android-x86

I WAS successfully installed Android-x86-v3.2-eeepc in VirtualBox for a while. And it is a good method to help me to debug USB host applications on Android. The installation of such configuration is:

- Install VirtualBox
- Install Android-x86-v3.2-eeepc image into virtual HDD in VBOX
- Set network as "host-only"
- Enter console, type "dhcpcd eth0" to get IP address, like "192.168.56.101"
- Go to console of host, type "adb connect 192.168.56.101"

Normally, it should be all right to get connected to adb daemon running in Android-in-VBox.

Today, it suddenly prompts me as following:

```
C:\>adb connect 192.168.56.101
unable to parse 192.168.56.101 as <host>:<port>
```

I tried to ping its IP. It has a fast response.
I tried to enforce IP and port.

```
C:\>adb connect 192.168.56.101:5554
unable to connect to 192.168.56.101:5554
```

I have no idea about its root cause. I checked the firewall, VirtualBox is on the Exception List. It still doesn't work.

PC Configuration:
Windows XP
VirtualBox V4.1

Comment: read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82825/how-i-can-improve-my-accept-rate-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To connect Android virtual machine with adb follow these step

1. On Android home screen, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (Left alt). This will open a terminal with root access.
2. Inside the terminal, type `dhcpcd eth0`. Execute the command twice, if you get an error or no result. This will give you an IP addresss. Now press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> for close the terminal.
3. Verify your IP address using the command `ping <your IP Address>`
4. From the android terminal, type `adb tcpip 5555`. This will restart adb in tcpip mode.
5. From your main OS terminal, type `adb connect <your IP address>`

Comment: It worked! These are the steps that I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. But the IP address set by `dhcpcd eth0` was not useful (it was `169.254.114.151`). I needed to use `dhcpcd eth1` instead. Also, after entering the command it did not returned the IP address. I entered `ifconfig eth1` to find the IP address (in front of `inet addr` field). By the way, I am using android-x86 6.0-r3 image.

Comment: Got `dhcpcd not found`

Answer (score 3):

I use bridged networking for the second adapter and use that IP address; i.e. `adb connect 192.168.1.20`.  You can get the IP in `Settings->About Phone->Status`.

Answer (score 0):

ALT+F1 trick looks good, but didn't work for me.

1. I did run androvmConfiguration app, clicked Save, and then confirmed
   reboot action.
2. After reboot, i did shutdown and turned off VirtualBox, and started AndroVMPlayer.
3. Now `adb connect <your IP address>` worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

It works for me instead of my local machine IP I inserted the android terminal IP
i.e 192.168.56.101