# Getting "error: device offline" from adb.exe in Android Player SDK / Setting Up Unity Remote 5 (Solved)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, path, remote-debugging

First of all, this is my first post here and I'm a beginner so my apologies if this ends up being a stupid question or my format is wrong, but any help is appreciated.

Essentially my problem is in trying to set up Unity Remote 5 for debugging in Unity. However, I believe I've finally narrowed it down. The error I'm getting now seems clear:

> CommandInvokationFailure: Unity Remote requirements check failed
> C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editors/2019.4.17f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\adb.exe forward tcp:7201 tcp:7201
> stderr[ error: device offline]
> stdout[]
> exit code: 1

I've looked into this error and came upon this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39031464/14948855 which seems like it might be useful to me, however the issue is I don't know how to run the commands he suggested and stack overflow made it clear it didn't want me posting a question as a response to that question and I don't have enough prestige to comment.

I'm trying to run "sudo adb kill-server" from an ubuntu linux terminal on windows from the directory abd is in (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editors\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools), but it won't run.

[proof command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cNn5.png)

I've tried adding it to the path on my computer: I added the directory listed above to "Path" in my "Environment Variables".

My phone is plugged in, I've disabled and reenabled developer mode and usb debugging, and restarted Unity and my phone several times. Any help with running this command in ubuntu or cmd, or even the greater problem of Unity Remote 5 would be fabulous.

Thank you.

Edit: here's a better image showing my issue:

[image showing how I've tried to add the folder to the path but it still can't be reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bwrh.png)

****Final Update:**
All my problems have been solved, here's how I got unity remote 5 for android working for posterity:**

step 1) Make sure phone is in developper mode (go to "about phone" in settings, tap build number 7 times).

step 2) Make sure "USB debugging" is turned on in developer options.

step 3) Make sure Unity is updated to the most  recent supported version through Unity Hub (might not be required but I did this step).

step 3) Download android support module through Unity Hub.

note: if you downloaded current Unity version from the Unity website rather than through Unity Hub, it doesn't seem to let you add modules to it through Unity Hub.

step 4) The sdk path Unity specifies by default is wrong for some reason, so in preferences->external tools, disable the default path and paste in the right directory (should be something like: *C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editors\2019.4.17f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK*) to be safe I did this for the JDK, NDK and Gradle too.

step 5) When you plug in phone, pull down your notifications, hit "tap to change USB options" and make sure phone is in "camera" mode or some variation. For me it was "Photo transfer".

Note: if you don't have the option to change USB options, try different usb ports/cables, if those don't work you might have debris in your charging port, clean it out with a dab of 91% or 99% rubbing alcohol and a tooth brush/tweezers (this will also make charger sit more snug in phone)

That might be enough to get it working for you, if not...

step 6) (Not sure if necessary) May need to update phone drivers in device manager on windows.

step 7) If Unity gives an adb error saying too many devices connected, it's possible you have a daemon running in the background which adb is picking up as an android emulator because it's using a port greater than 5555. It seems adb checks open ports above port 5555, and assumes anything it finds is an emulator. To check this, as indicated in my original question, and as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39031464/14948855, in cmd on windows use adb devices (if ur on linux may need to use sudo) to get a list of all devices being detected by adb. (Also use "adb kill-server" to reset it.) If there is an emulator being detected, it should include the port it's using in its name, in my case it was "emulator-5562" in port 5562, which was apparently actually NTKDaemon from Native Instuments, a random music production program I've only used once so far. I'd suggest googling the emulator port you find to try and narrow down the process taking that port. The only thing left to do is to kill the process running in the port. I found NTKDaemon in task manager and also disabled it activating on startup because that's just evil imo.

And that should be it. Hope that works for you if you're here for help.

(btw in terms of my original question, I was able to access adb.exe by changing the directory in cmd, but I still never found why adding the directory to the path didn't work, so if anyone has an answer to that I would be interested)

Comment: Sudo is for linux. The oath you provided is windows. So no. Sudo wont help you. Why do it from a linux terminal? Adb.exe is a window program not a linux one

Comment: sorry @BugFinder I shouldn've included that I have tried that as well. I can't seem to post an image here in this reply, but I've edited my original question to include a screenshot showing the issue more in depth.

Comment: Update: I was able to reach adb.exe by changing the directory in cmd (huzzah), but I am still confused why adding the directory to the path didn't work.

Comment: Did you edit the path under linux or windows? Root or another user?

Comment: @BugFinder I believe it was windows User. I went to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> User variables for *username* -> Path. The same way I added my Java jdk a while ago. When that didn't work I also tried adding to the Path under "System Variables" but that didn't seem to work either.